# Send vector of class C++ pointers to python

Tags: python, class, wrapper, root-framework

I have a problem with passing std vector to python.

```
   std::vector<TMVA::Interval*> parameterRanges;
   parameterRanges.push_back(new TMVA::Interval(-10,10)); 
   parameterRanges.push_back(new TMVA::Interval(0.1,10)); 
   parameterRanges.push_back(new TMVA::Interval(0,2000));
```

And I have to do that in python. unfortunately I can not change Interval C++ class.
I can use std.vector in python, but only std.vector('double') or int, but not object type.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Can you access `TMVA::Interval` in Python without putting it in a vector? That would be the problem you would have to solve first.

Answer (score 3):

As you're using TMVA, I assume you're also having ROOT. There is also a ROOT std::vector wrapper for use in pyroot. It is used as follows:

```
import ROOT
VectorOfIntervalPointer = ROOT.std.vector('TMVA::Interval*')
# this is only a constructor, not an instance!

instance = VectorOfIntervalPointer()
from ROOT import TMVA.Interval
instance.push_back(TMVA.Interval(-10,10))
```